# Can I add new hard drives without restarting?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, windows-server-2012-r2, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge R720 with a PERC H710P Mini controller. I currently have 10 disks in a RAID10 array, and I need to expand the array, or create a new virtual disk with 2 new 1.2TB disks I have.

Can I plug the new hard drives into the server without taking it offline? Or is this a bad idea, and should I just wait until we can shut the server down? The drives are Enterprise 10K 1.2TB Dell drives.

Comment: All sata drives are hot swappable.

Comment: @IporSircer Correct. But not all *controllers* are (though I suspect the PERC H710 is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This controller is definitely hot-swappable, and the Poweredge R720 comes with caddies to even make this easy.  The whole idea of this setup is to be able to hot-swap failing disks.

You can control changes to arrays using a [difficult-to-use piece of software called MegaCli](http://erikimh.com/megacli-cheatsheet/) (which is available for both Windows and Linux).   It may also be useful to know that the PERC controller is made by LSI.

(As an aside most SATA controllers - or at least most ones using an Intel chipset) allow hotswapping are if you are careful - but they are not neccessarily designed to be!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Idrac card embedded card if you have it/can use it or [Dell OpenManage System Administrator](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en/en/frbsdt1/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/enterprise-resource-center/systemsmanagement/OMSA).

It's a dell official tool, windows and Linux compatible (even Debian too which is not listed on official doc).